# Iterating hierarchy of nodes - Visitor and Composite?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, composite, visitor-pattern

Let's imagine I have a collection of nodes that I use for my Renderer class later on. Then I have a Visitor class that can visit node or whole collection. It's simple because my collection of nodes it's simply a wrapper to the std::list with few extra methods.

The problem is I'd like to have a tree like structure for nodes(instead of simple list) so a node can have a parent and n children. That would be handy as I'd like to be able to pass to my Renderer a node and render everything "below" that node. The answer probably is Composite.

How can I use together Visitor and Composite? I've read that its often a good combo but my implementations look pretty bad... I'm missing sth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have something very similar implemented for our system. I wanted a way to compose hierarchy of geometrical object and render them into the volume. I used composite pattern to compose my description (root was Node and then derived child was compositeNode (list of Nodes).

CompositeNode has method accept() which accepts a visitor (Visitor) and then inside the accept() you do visitor->visit(this).

Thus your visitor hierarchy has base class as NodeVisitor and derived visitors like RenderVisitor (renders objects), ReportVisitor (dumped node info into text). Your base class will need to accept both base and specialized node types.

So yes, combo works and I have working code but I agree that design takes more effort than what you would read online (Wiki or toy example).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple example:

```
struct NodeVisitor;

struct Node
{
  virtual ~Node() {}
  virtual void accept(NodeVisitor &v);
};

struct CompositeNode : public Node
{
  virtual void accept(NodeVisitor &v);
  std::list<NodePtr> nodes_;
};

struct NodeVisitor
{
  virtual ~NodeVisitor() {}
  virtual void visit(Node &n) = 0;
  virtual void visit(CompositeNode &cn)
  {
    for(std::list<NodePtr>::iterator it = cn.nodes_.begin(), end = cn.nodes_.end(); it != end; ++it)
    {
      (*it)->accept(*this);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Why are you invoking `accept`s of node children in `NodeVisitor`?

Comment: @user35443: Because otherwise visitation would stop and since the OP asked for how to combine Visitor with Composite that needs to include visitation of all nodes in the Composite, otherwise it would just be Visitor. Info about visitor: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern. Info about composite: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern

Comment: Yes, but I mean I've been looking at hierarchial for a while, and wherever I looked I found the iteration of composite members in the Nodes, not Visitor.

Comment: @user35443: Well, you could do it either way. There are pros and cons with each. Doing the iteration in the visitor gives you more flexibility. Doing it in the composite node let's you write it once and then forget about it. Typically for most real world cases I've encountered, I've needed that extra flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your visitor also to know the structure of the tree (e.g. the depth it is visiting or the path from the tree root) you could consider using the hierarchical visitor pattern.
This is described somewhat lengthy at [c2.com wiki](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?HierarchicalVisitorPattern)

It also shows how to skip an 'uninteresting' branch.