# C++ example of implementation composite and visitor pattern together

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Now I'm developing a specialized vector editor. Can you tell me where I can see a good example (only C++ language ) of source (not standard book example) implementation composite and visitor pattern together.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterating hierarchy of nodes - Visitor and Composite ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538856/iterating-hierarchy-of-nodes-visitor-and-composite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composite + visitor isn't such a popular pair, in most cases you can see composite + iterator ... so you will have to try add them by your own hands, but it shouldn't be hard. In both patterns you have inteface implemented by concrete classes, so you have to fill your composite with visitor ideas

http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite/cpp/2

http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite/cpp/1

http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor

gl :)

Comment: I know how ot use google search and see this example, but i can to see real little opensouce project, but not simple examples

Comment: @G-71 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538856/itereting-hierarchy-of-nodes-visitor-and-composite maybe this can help?

Comment: I see this question and see many pages from google, but this is a simple examples

Comment: Simple example it's always a start point. Waiting for someone knowing some specified open source project, with will to help, can take years.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search gave me these implementation examples of Composite Pattern:

- [C++ example for Composite Design Pattern](http://advancedcppwithexamples.blogspot.com/2010/09/c-example-for-composite-design-pattern.html)
- [Composite design pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite/cpp/1)
- [Composite design pattern - multiple container classes](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite/cpp/2)
- [Composite Pattern Made as C++ Component](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/CompositePatternComponent.aspx)

Comment: Please read my question. "composite and visitor pattern together".

Comment: Oops someone gave me downvotes, as if I should provide the implementation myself.

Comment: Yes, give you downvote, because your links is links of simple example implemetational this patterns

Comment: @G-71: Awesome. I'm trying to help you by wasting my time, and you gave me downvote just because it didn't help you? So that's kind of punishment for attempting to help you?

Comment: ok, sorry, i will cancel downvote, but quick search in google... it isn't help to me

Comment: @G-71: If it's not a help for you, then that's fine, you can ignore my post, but downvote by OP himself is something that discourages people from answering your question. It's as if you're taking my exams. Also, if the link which explains the pattern with simple example, doesn't help you, then it's YOUR problem, not mine. You like to be spoonfeed, maybe?

Comment: @G-71: why don't you take one of Nawaz examples and add the missing accept(Visitor vis) { vis.action(this); } method? If you can not do that, you don't need the 2 patterns but a serious course in basic programming.

Answer (score 0):

This [example source code](https://github.com/kkruecke/composite-iterator) is based upon the file system example found in the book **Pattern Hatching: Design Patterns Applied**, by John Vlissides, which uses Composite and Visitor. (The code includes external iterator that is not in the book).

Free slides detailing the example from the book are at [Designing with Patterns](http://www.cs.olemiss.edu/~hcc/softwareDesign/notes/Designing_with_patterns.ppt).